# File input custom text in jQuery and CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was successful in customizing the file input using jQuery and CSS3.

However, there is one thing I was not able to do. I want to show the text of the file selected after the user selected the image or file at the very bottom of the text like this:

[image]

So far here's my codes. Here's the HTML:

```
 <div class="container-avatar">
                    <div class="avatar-upload">
                      <div class="avatar-edit">
                        <input accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" id="imageUpload" type='file'> <label for="imageUpload"></label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="avatar-preview">
                        <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url('http://softorius.ro/images/about1.jpg');"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.container-avatar {
  max-width: 115px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.avatar-upload {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input {
  display: none;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input+label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input+label:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input+label:after {
  content: "\f040";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #007BFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-preview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #F8F8F8;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-preview>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
 function readURL(input) {
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function(e) {
             $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
             $('#imagePreview').hide();
             $('#imagePreview').fadeIn(650);
         }
         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
  }
  $("#imageUpload").change(function() {
     readURL(this);
  });
```

All of my codes are hosted on JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/wtvrzj91/1/

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty easy and actually you already are reading the file data here:

[image: Input file name]

To get the name you need to access to the name property: input.files[0].name and to populate it just create a div, and with javascript insert the string to that div, example:

HTML:

```
<div class="imageFilename"></div>
```

Javascript(inside readURL function):

```
document.querySelector(".imageFilename").innerHTML = input.files[0].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

From this below snippet to set **file name** text on **bottom** side of selected image area.

I have little bit *changes into your css* code because you can not set display:none **(input[type="file"])** due to Safari browser instructions so we can use **opacity:0** and I set edit icon ***middle+center*** in circle div and set input[type="file"] inside **label** element so now you can ***drag and drop*** image file on edit icon area.

Also tested *drag-n-drop* its working.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
   $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
   $('#imagePreview').hide().fadeIn(650);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    $('.imageFilename').html(input.files[0].name).attr('title', input.files[0].name);
  }
}
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
.container-avatar {
  max-width: 115px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.avatar-upload {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit label{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input{
 position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit label:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit label:after{
  content: "\f040";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #007BFF;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-preview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #F8F8F8;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-preview>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.imageFilename{
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<br><br>

<div class="container-avatar">
  <div class="avatar-upload">
    <div class="avatar-edit">
      <label title="Upload Image"><input accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" id="imageUpload" type='file'></label>
    </div>
    <div class="avatar-preview">
      <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url('http://softorius.ro/images/about1.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imageFilename"></div>
</div>
```